# Recently versions of firefox/palemoon have been really slow to start

Tags: linux, firefox, performance, manjaro, palemoon

Both Firefox and Palemoon have been starting super slow on my i3 manjaro  recently. Can take more then a minute before I see any screen. It runs fine after it has started up.

I am at a loss to figure out what is causing this slowness.

```
uname -a
Linux laptop-pc 5.3.8-3-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Nov 3 14:19:23 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Browser versions

```
Firefox version 70.0.1
Palemoon version 28.7.1
```

I have tried a [number of performance enhancements](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solving-the-slow-and-laggy-firefox-problem/20468). 
Most of them are about improving performance after it is already started.

This slowness started of a recent clean re-installation of my os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this issue for a few months.

I finally found out what the problem was with the slow startups.

```
hostname
newname-pc

sudo vim /etc/hosts
...
127.0.1.1   old-pc newname-pc
...
```

on some systems the loopback ip could be `127.0.0.1`.

Once I added the hostname to the hosts file and I could now resolve newname-pc to an IP address firefox starts up instantly.

Slow startups because my local hostname was changed after my installation. 
Firefox and palemoon both do a resolve on the local hostname during startup and will only complete the startup after this has timed out or resolved.

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1504783#p1504783
- https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/478160-Firefox-starts-slowly?s=25bba8356f20516323a01c0ed099ea3c&p=2485636#post2485636

Comment: Thanks! This has been driving me nuts.

Comment: This also affected LibreOffice having multiple crashes. 
After putting in the hostname / ip mapping that was resolved as well.